# Creating and canceling an NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a NSURLConnection that is working fine when I allow the load to complete.  But if the user hits the back button, meaning the webview will dissappear, I want to cancel the NSURLConnection in progress. But if have the webview call into this class when viewWillDissapear is called, and then I do:

```
[conn cancel]
```

I get an NSINValidArgument exception.

The connection is defined as instance data in the .h file as:

```
NSURLConnection *conn;
```

The async is initiated here:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:articleURL]];

    if ([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request] && reachable) {
        // Set up an asynchronous load request
        conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        loadCancelled = NO;
        if (conn) {
            NSLog(@" ARTICLE is REACHABLE!!!!");
            self.articleData = [NSMutableData data];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why you got the exception would be you are saving an autorelease object to an instance variable.
"conn" would be auto-released immediately when a user click back button. After that, you call cancel. Therefore, you had the exception.
To prevent this, you should retain NSURLConnection object when you keep it in an instance variable.

```
conn = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] retain];
```

or

```
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Don't forget to release this in the dealloc method.