# setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible to NO in viewDidDisappear

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

There is no way to automatically cancel a url connection, so here is how I do it:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Yes, I know it doesn't actually cancel the request, it just hides the network indicator in the status bar, and the request is still doing somewhere in the background.

For now it works, but is this Apple-safe?
Would Apple like it, or they will reject my app for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your app will not be rejected. You can cancel the request, refer to this answer [Creating and canceling an NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126056/creating-and-canceling-an-nsurlconnection). If you're using `ASIHTTPRequest`, retain it and call `[request cancel];` in `willDissapear:animated:`

Comment: Well I'm using asynchronous nsurlconnection.

Answer (score 0):

You should just offload your URLRequests to a separate class. This is referred to as MVC. You can set the NetworkActivityIndicator to animate or stop in that class, and that class can run behind the scenes and you don't have to worry about making your ViewController be in charge of the indicator.

It's good practice to keep the user informed of what's going on, and the network activity feedback is good to see, especially if i'm waiting for something to happen.